# Child Float Divs Breaking out of Parent Div

Tags: css, html, css-float

I've read through a lot of other posts on here about this issue to no effect. I wish to have a background graphic extend the whole length of the page, but it only goes 2/3 of the way down.

```
html, body { height: 100%; }

div#body-wrapper {
   height:100%;
   position:relative;
}

nav#side-navigation {
   height:100%;
   width:185px;
   background-color:#C2F4C2;
   float:left;
}

div#content-wrap {
   width:775px;
   height:100%;
   float:right;
   position:relative;
   background:transparent url(../images/global/column_corner.gif) no-repeat top left;
}
```

If I add *overflow:hidden* to #body-wrapper, it cuts off a portion of the bottom of the website.

Finally, here's active source code: http://freshbaby.com/v20/about_us/index.cfm

Comment: Can you show your HTML structure

Comment: Any reason you can't put the background-image on the body, or the html?

Comment: It's on my local machine only, so I cannot provide a url.

Answer (score 5):

You can add an element after the floating elements to 'clear' the floats.

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: It pushed the main content below the navigation.

Comment: The clear needs to go below both of the floating columns, not just the main content.

Answer (score 4):

You should clear:both after the floats.

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this was ever solved, but try adding the following to body and html:
padding: 0;
margin: 0;

If that doesn't do the trick completely, then put your background image on the html selector with the following attr:`background: url(../assets/image.jpg);-moz-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 1):

Something very helpful to remember is the break tag also clears floats.

```
<br clear='left'/>
<br clear='right'/>
<br clear='all'/>
```